# re regex find first half but keep second half of line

Tags: python, regex

Folks, doing my head in trying to search this question, as I find it strange to describe briefly...

I am trying to strip out unnecessary text from a bank statement eg:

```
source: TFR 09343-9724 to their bank-Client Company Invoice 238923
output: Client Company Invoice 238923
```

I thought the simplest way would be to search for the "TFR 09343-9724 to their bank-" and junk that, keeping the remainder. I can't set that as a search pattern as the client reference changes ... although in retrospect I guess a regex could handle a changing Invoice number easily enough...

I'll see if I can't do that now but I'm still curious how I might use "re" to implement my original idea.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below regex and remove the matched string through `re.sub` function

```
TFR 09343-9724.*?bank-
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/gK8hF6/1)

```
>>> import re
>>> m = re.sub(r'TFR 09343-9724.*?bank-', r'', 'TFR 09343-9724 to their bank-Client Company Invoice 238923')
>>> m
'Client Company Invoice 238923'
```

OR

Use the below regex if you don't know the number after `TFR`

```
>>> m = re.sub(r'\bTFR \d+-\d+\b.*?bank-', r'', 'TFR 09343-9724 to their bank-Client Company Invoice 238923')
>>> m
'Client Company Invoice 238923'
```

Comment: Thank you, I was (also it seems) having some trouble between using single and double quotes. Is there a distinction you can easily make for me?

Comment: distinction? sorry i didn't get your point. could you explain it clearly for me?

Comment: I was using ("some text") rather than ('some text') which seemed to change my success/failure.

Answer (score 1):

You can capture just the rest of the relevant line(s):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = """some first line
some other line
TFR 09343-9724 to their bank-Client Company Invoice 238923
a final line"""
>>> re.search(r"^TFR \d{5}-\d{4}.*-(.*)$", s, re.MULTILINE).groups()
('Client Company Invoice 238923',)
```

Note the parentheses around the second `.*`, followed by the end-of-line character `$` - this means "capture everything in the rest of the line" (see [demo and full explanation here](http://regex101.com/r/wQ5pB7/1)).